# How to listen to my iPod on an other computer?

Tags: itunes, ipod

I have an iPod and it is synchronised on a computer A.

I would like to listen to my music on another computer B, on which iTunes 11 is installed.

When I connect the iPod on the computer B, I am able to see all the screens related to the settings, such as [image] or [image]
but I don't know how to actually access the content of the iPod to play the music.

Is it possible ?

And, if yes, what should I do  ?

---

EDIT : When I click on "Sur cet iPod" ("On this iPod"), I am able to see the content of the iPod but it seems that I canno't play it... Any advice ? Here is the screen :[image]

Comment: Ate the tw computers on the same network - if so use shared libraries and you don't need to involve the iPod

Comment: The other computer is not here !!!

Answer (score 2):

When your iPod is plugged in, just go to `Sur cet iPod` (On this iPod) and you can actually play the music from your iPod.

Comment: So easy !! And can I play this music ?

Comment: Yes. But it will stop when you unplug your iPod.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! but (see the edit), the songs are "grayed" and it seems that I canno't play them !

Comment: Were the grayed out songs downloaded from iTunes, and possibly require that you authenticate that computer before than can be played?

Comment: Some of them were downloaded from iTunes, but others were imported from a CD. But, both are grayed !

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the iPod to manually manage music

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/playing-your-iPod-through-iTunes.html